# Make addAction work for android notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-service, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to do something when user hits action button in the notification. Notifications are showing with action button present. Yet for some reason, action is not firing; receiver is not getting the message. In fact, neither receiver is getting the intent - WakefulBroadcastReceiver (for alerts), BootReceiver (to set up alert upon boot).

The code is below:

```
public class OSService extends IntentService {

        // Call this method from onHandleIntent
        private void createNotification(OrderSearch search)
            {
                String name = search.getName();
                NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                Intent intent = new Intent("snooze");
                PendingIntent snoozer = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
                        .setContentTitle(df.format(search.getOrderCount()) + " orders")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notify2))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_alarm_off_black_18dp, "for today", snoozer)
                        .setContentText(name);


                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                manager.notify(1, builder.build());
            }
}
```

In manifest file:

```
<application ...>
   <receiver a:name=".ActionReceiver"/>
</application>
```

The action receiver:

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Action: " + intent.getAction());
            }
    }
```

I've been banging my head on the wall for a few days and can't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Intent` is for an action of `"snooze"`. Your `<receiver>` does not have an `<intent-filter>`, let alone one for `"snooze"`. If you are intending to invoke `ActionReceiver` for the `Notification` action, replace:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("snooze");
```

with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActionReceiver.class);
```

Comment: This works exactly as needed! The reason for no <intent-filter> is that I want to utilize static final fields. But not constructing Intent like so... well, makes me feel stupid. Thank you for pointing out the oversight.